# regular epxression (sass variables)

Tags: node.js, regex

(Node.js) I have to match all Sass variables from file. But I can have variables and mixins in one file. I need to update regular epxression to not match a variables from mixin directive or from mixin / function content (nested).

So only:

1. $test: true;
2. $white: #fff !default;
3. $sizes: (25: 0.25rem, 50: 0.5rem) !default;

Regular expression: `/\$([^:]*)\s*:\s*([^;]*)\s*;/g`

https://regex101.com/r/oRuWjS/1

```
$test: true;

$white: #fff !default;

$sizes: (
  25: 0.25rem,
  50: 0.5rem
) !default;

@mixin parent ($first, $second: "") {
  .#{$first} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `@mixin[^(]*\([^{]*({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})(*SKIP)(*F)|\$([^:]*?)\s*:\s*([^;]*?)\s*;`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oRuWjS/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok It works but I am using JS not PHP... your REGEXP does not work for JS

Comment: Please change the tags then, and add the code you tried.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying to create a parser for Node.js... sorry I did not mention it... Is It possible in JS? SKIP etc. does not exist in JS REGEXPs

Comment: I do not know what you have done so far. You should stick to writing a parser without a regex for this scenario. Recursion is not supported even in ECMAScript 2018 powered JS regexps.

Comment: Ok, here is a suggestion: match from `@mixin` to the `}` that is alone on a line, and skip this match, else collect your other matches. See https://regex101.com/r/Xcwr8G/1. 
Only get the data to the resulting array if Group 2 & 3 are matched (and if Group 1 matched, discard this match). Can we rely on the indentation?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
/@mixin[^(]*\([\s\S]*?^}$|\$([^:]*?)\s*:\s*([^;]*?)\s*;/gm
```

you may match from `@mixin` to the `}` that is alone on a line, and skip this match, else collect your other matches. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xcwr8G/2).

```js
var s = "$test: true;\n\n$white: #fff !default;\n\n$sizes: (\n  25: 0.25rem,\n  50: \n0.5rem\n) !default;\n\n@mixin parent ($first, $second: \"\") {\n  .#{$first} {\n    \n@content;\n  }\n}\n";
var rx = /@mixin[^(]*\([\s\S]*?^}$|\$([^:]*?)\s*:\s*([^;]*?)\s*;/gm;
var m, res = [];
while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
   if (m[1]) {
       res.push([m[1], m[2]]);
   }
}
console.log(res);
```

**Details**

- `@mixin[^(]*\([\s\S]*?^}$` - the alternative that will be skipped:

  - `@mixin` - a literal substring
  - `[^(]*` - 0+ chars other than `(`
  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
  - `^}$` - a `}` that is on a separate line
- `|` - or
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `([^:]*?)` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than `:` as few as possible
- `\s*:\s*` -  a `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `([^;]*?)` - Group 2: 0+ chars other than `:` as few as possible
- `\s*;` - 0+ whitespaces followed with `;`.